# A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' (type 'GoogleServicesTask')

Tags: android, gradle

A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' (type 'GoogleServicesTask').

- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\project\ocpp-android-master\app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug'.

- Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.internal.execution.WorkValidationException: A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' (type 'GoogleServicesTask').

  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\project\ocpp-android-master\app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug'.

    Reason: Task ':app:mergeDebugResources' uses this output of task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.

    Possible solutions:

    1. Declare task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' as an input of ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
    2. Declare an explicit dependency on ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' from ':app:mergeDebugResources' using Task#dependsOn.
    3. Declare an explicit dependency on ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' from ':app:mergeDebugResources' using Task#mustRunAfter.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.7.6'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.7.6'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.7.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:6.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2"
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.github.yuriy-budiyev:code-scanner:2.1.2'

}
```

build.gradle

Comment: found any solution?

Comment: did you fix this ? found any solution? –